# when condition in where

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've two tables. And one product has 2 price and I need to compare max_count with quantity and should select only one record
My query is not working..

```
   SELECT product_id, quantity, max_count 
    FROM table1 WHERE WHEN max_count > quantity 
    THEN price_type = 1 ELSE price_type = 2 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id
```

Comment: You're missing 'Case' and your Where should come after you joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use basic logic.  The clauses of your query are also in the wrong order:

```
SELECT product_id, quantity, max_count 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id
WHERE (max_count > quantity AND price_type = 1) OR
      (max_count <= quantity AND price_type = 2);
```

If `max_count` can take on the value of `NULL`, the logic is slightly more complicated.